# How to update BAKER_ACCOUNT and ENDORSER_ACCOUNT?

Tags: baker, endorser

As per the guide here https://github.com/serokell/tezos-packaging/blob/master/docs/baking.md

As mentioned in baking guide

Apart from that, you'll need to update the `BAKER_ACCOUNT` and `ENDORSER_ACCOUNT` (in `/etc/default/tezos-baker-<proto>` and `/etc/default/tezos-endorser-<proto>` respectively) in accordance to the alias of the imported key.

Also I tried to start baker node by command  `sudo systemctl start tezos-baker-008-ptedo2zk.service` But it gives error like

```
Apr 27 14:37:35 ip-172-31-71-16 tezos-baker-start[3240]: Error: Apr 27 14:37:35 ip-172-31-71-16 tezos-baker-start[3240]:   Erroneous command line argument 5 ().  Apr 27 14:37:35 ip-172-31-71-16 tezos-baker-start[3240]:   Directory doesn't exist: ''
```

Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that step you'll need to edit the content of the two file mentioned, replacing `<proto>` in the name with the protocol you intend to use, and setting the alias(es) to the `BAKER_ACCOUNT` and `ENDORSER_ACCOUNT` options in them.

For example (at the time of writing, Ubuntu packages version `9.0-1`), if you are using `edo2net`  and the alias for your baker account is `baker`, you'll need to edit the `/etc/default/tezos-baker-008-ptedo2zk` and replace the last line :

```
BAKER_ACCOUNT=""
```

with one containing the alias:

```
BAKER_ACCOUNT="baker"
```

likewise you'll also need to edit `/etc/default/tezos-endorser-008-ptedo2zk` and replace the last line:

```
ENDORSER_ACCOUNT=""
```

with (here I'm using the same account):

```
ENDORSER_ACCOUNT="baker"
```